# Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-match

I use CI_Minifier and have problems after I have updated my PHP.

Now I receive an error when I use the `preg_match` function.

```php
if (!preg_match("/^[\w-:]+$/", $tag)) { #error line
    $node->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT] = '<' . $tag . $this->copy_until('<>');
    if ($this->char === '<') {
        $this->link_nodes($node, false);

        return true;
    }

    if ($this->char==='>') {
        $node->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT] .= '>';
    }
    $this->link_nodes($node, false);
    $this->char = (++$this->pos<$this->size) ? $this->doc[$this->pos] : null; // next

    return true;
}
```

The error is:

> Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4

Comment: Very likely it is that `$this->doc` has less than 4 elements but `$this->pos` equals 4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Escape the hyphen:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[\w\-:]+$/", $tag)) {
```

or put it at the beginning of character class:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[-\w:]+$/", $tag)) {
```

or at the end:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[\w:-]+$/", $tag)) {
```

Comment: I wonder how you thought to escape the hyphen? Was it a chance thing like most of my discoveries? Either way - thank you for your experience, it saved me a major brain drain and time. Is this relative to PHP versions? I wonder..

Comment: @ScottFleming: It's a generic error. `invalid range in character class` got self explanation. To be sure, **always** escape the hyphen in a character class.